# Apex Log manager needed, or way how to filter big amount of logs

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, vs-code, debug, debug-logs

I'm looking for some tool, or extension for managing/ searching Apex logs.

My main problem is I can produce very easily, a lot of logs by myself and ofc I'm not alone.
Basically, when I reload one site, I'm working on, I can create up to 70 logs and if someone is working in the same time, is very problematic to find anything.

I would like something that allowed me to filter logs by user, time and phrase. It would be really nice if I would be able to delete those logs as well.

I'm working on VS Code and unfortunately I couldn't find any extension like that, but as far I know there is a tool like that in intellij.

I found Maven extension for chrome, it doesn't have those filters. It works, but I have a problem, that every time I have to select my last 40 logs by myself or search phrase through 2000 logs.

I saw also that I can use CLI's command sfdx force:apex:log:get but by this way I can only retrieve up to 25 logs. (and also I have problems with user filtering I feel it is not good describe)

And the last way is to use a query and select logs and later use a loop with HTTP Request inside.
But I don't feel its the best solution.

Please guys help me. I'm struggling with that for a while.